# fixed size buffer array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I trying to write a program which in which the buffer area should be of fixed size.By fixed I mean upper bound to be fixed. The program should remove first element shift array to the left by 1 and the new element at end of buffer array.

Example:
     output should be like: 1234   2345   3456 where last digit is the input

This is what I have tried

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
char buffer[5]="1234";        //5 for '\0'
//char buffer[]="";

char pattern[]="1234";

char ch;


int idxToDel = 0; 
while(1){
  scanf("%c",&ch);
memmove(&buffer[idxToDel], &buffer[idxToDel + 1], strlen(buffer) - idxToDel);
buffer[3]=ch;
printf("%s",buffer);
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you are asking about a **circular queue**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You've mentioned what you tried, but not what worked and what didn't.  If you could describe that, and specify what your question is, we would be better able to help you.

Comment: I want a program which has infinite inputs and it stores the last four inputs in a array so that I compare it with a pattern with strcmp()

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your program to get no warnings. **Use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: I would generally implement a circular buffer with pointers to the beginning and end, rather than actually moving the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem in your program is with this statement:

```
scanf("%c",&ch);
```

When you enter a character and press "Enter" key, after pressing "Enter" key, the `'\n'` character still left in the input stream and the next call to `scanf`, in your infinite `while` loop, will consume it and the next value of ch will be `\n` character.

To overcome this problem put a blank space before the conversion specifier in the format string:

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
```

The second problem is this statement:

```
memmove(&buffer[idxToDel], &buffer[idxToDel + 1], strlen(buffer) - idxToDel);
```

This is logically incorrect.

Since `idxToDel` value is 0, so this `memmove` will try to move the `strlen(buffer) - 0` (= 4) bytes from source `&buffer[0 + 1]` to destination `&buffer[0]` (which decays to `buffer`). But in your case, you only need to move 3 characters.

The `memmove()` function does not check for any terminating null character in source - it always copies exactly number of bytes.

So, you can do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
        char buffer[5]="1234";        //5 for '\0'
        char ch;
        int indxtomove = 1;

        printf ("%s\n", buffer);

        while(1){
                scanf(" %c",&ch);
                memmove(buffer, &buffer[indxtomove], strlen(buffer) - indxtomove);
                buffer[3]=ch;
                printf("%s\n",buffer);
        }
        return 0;
}
```